# How do I normalize temporal data to their initial values?

Tags: c, matlab, plot, normalization, auc

I have  data that are acquired every 3 seconds. Initially, they always begin within a narrow baseline range (i.e. 100±10) but after ~30 seconds they begin to increase in value.

Here's an example.

[image]

The issue is that for every experiment, the initial baseline value may start at a different point in the y-axis (i.e. 100, 250, 35) due to variations in equipment calibration.

Although the relative signal enhancement at ~30 seconds behaves the same across different experiments, there may be an offset along the y-axis.

My intention is to measure the AUC of these curves. Because of the offset between experiments, they are not comparable, although they could potentially be identical in shape and enhancement ratio.

Therefore I need to normalize the data so that regardless of offset they all have comparable baseline initial values. This could be set to 0.

Can you give me any suggestions on how to accomplish the normalization on Matlab?

Ideally the output data should be of relative signal enhancement (in percent relative to baseline).

For example, the baseline values above would hover around 0±10 (instead of the raw original value of ~139) and with enhancement they would build up to ~65% (instead of the original raw value of ~230).

Sample data:

```
 index       SQMean   
_____    ____________

'0'      '139.428574'
'1'      '133.298706'
'2'      '135.961044'
'3'      '143.688309'
'4'      '133.298706'
'5'      '133.181824'
'6'      '134.896103'
'7'      '146.415588'
'8'      '142.324677'
'9'      '128.168839'
'10'     '146.116882'
'11'     '146.766235'
'12'     '134.675323'
'13'     '138.610382'
'14'     '140.558441'
'15'     '128.662338'
'16'     '138.480515'
'17'     '153.610382'
'18'     '156.207794'
'19'     '183.428574'
'20'     '220.324677'
'21'     '224.324677'
'22'     '230.415588'
'23'     '226.766235'
'24'     '223.935059'
'25'     '229.922073'
'26'     '234.389618'
'27'     '235.493500'
'28'     '225.727280'
'29'     '241.623383'
'30'     '225.805191'
'31'     '240.896103'
'32'     '224.090912'
'33'     '230.467529'
'34'     '248.285721'
'35'     '233.779221'
'36'     '225.532471'
'37'     '247.337662'
'38'     '233.000000'
'39'     '241.740265'
'40'     '235.688309'
'41'     '238.662338'
'42'     '236.636368'
'43'     '236.025970'
'44'     '234.818176'
'45'     '240.974030'
'46'     '251.350647'
'47'     '241.857147'
'48'     '242.623383'
'49'     '245.714279'
'50'     '250.701294'
'51'     '229.415588'
'52'     '236.909088'
'53'     '243.779221'
'54'     '244.532471'
'55'     '241.493500'
'56'     '245.480515'
'57'     '244.324677'
'58'     '244.025970'
'59'     '231.987015'
'60'     '238.740265'
'61'     '239.532471'
'62'     '232.363632'
'63'     '242.454544'
'64'     '243.831161'
'65'     '229.688309'
'66'     '239.493500'
'67'     '247.324677'
'68'     '245.324677'
'69'     '244.662338'
'70'     '238.610382'
'71'     '243.324677'
'72'     '234.584412'
'73'     '235.181824'
'74'     '228.974030'
'75'     '228.246750'
'76'     '230.519485'
'77'     '231.441559'
'78'     '236.324677'
'79'     '229.935059'
'80'     '238.701294'
'81'     '236.441559'
'82'     '244.350647'
'83'     '233.714279'
'84'     '243.753250'
```

Comment: Why not take the average of the first, say, 5 sec and subtract this value from all measurements, thus eliminating the DC offset of your experiments?

Comment: Would that give me a relative signal enhancement value? (I'll add this to OP)

Comment: it's unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Seconding @Shai. There are a lot of ad hoc methods one could invent, but without knowing something about what your data are, why the baseline is changing, what the AUC is meant to measure etc. its hard to give sound advice.

Comment: let me try to explain better on OP, thx

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. Does one of the answers solve it for you? If not, I have two follow-up questions: Is the baseline change additive (everthing is 50 units higher or 20 lower) or multiplicative (everything is 20% higher or 10% lower). I assume the latter, because otherwise an enhancement factor doesn't make sense. Second: Do you know when exactly the baseline ends and the increase happens? – Also, could you post one example data set?

Comment: thanks @donda--the output for baseline change should be multiplicative--baseline ends at the 10th data point along x-axis--will post sample data

Comment: Thanks. But then I think A. Klomp's answer is correct, with `nrSamp = 10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close to what was mentioned by Shai:

```
blwindow = 1:nrSamp;
DataNorm = 100*(Data/mean(Data(blwindow))-1)
```

Set the window to the right size, however you want to determine it, it depends on your data. Output DataNorm is in %.

Comment: why do you subtract 1 from the division between Data and mean baseline value?

Comment: The division puts the baseline average on 100%. In line with your question where you mention: "would build up to ~65%". Divide by baseline gives you 165%, not 65% after the "build up". I've taken 1 off (100%) to show the _variation from baseline_, in terms of percentage baseline, so: "a 65% increase".

Comment: thanks--what do you think of normalizing by doing `(x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin)`? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range For my data, `xmin` would be the baseline mean. Any reason you'd prefer the way you propose instead?

Comment: That would result in a signal starting at 0 average (baseline data oscillating around 0) and peaking at 1. I don't know what your application is so I find it hard to say how that can be used/what that means. Note that if your xmax is a spike, you will be normalizing to it. I'm generally working with EMG, where I want to compare sizes of responses of different subjects (different traces), and the normalization to the range would throw that out the window. I'm happy to chat about your problem and options, if you prefer. - this doesn't have much to do with your initial question.

Comment: Sorry I now see your question states that your looking for an AUC. If you normalize to range, your AUC will be (mostly) determined by the timing of the onset. Without knowing your use, not a good idea, i'd say.

Comment: thanks for the valuable feedback--this is for MRI-DCE perfusion curves, so I'd also be comparing between subjects, and yes there may be spikes (up or down) that could bias the normalization in my datasets. would love to chat more--doesn't SE have a chat forum?

Comment: Sorry, I thought SE did have a chat, but can't see any way of finding it, or sending you personal messages.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this kind of problems requires some more specific knowledge about the data you are measuring (range, noise level, if you know when the actual data starts etc.) and the results you are trying to achieve. However, based on your question only and by looking at your example graph, I'd do something like this (assuming your data is in two arrays, `time` and `data`):

```
initialTimeMax = 25; % take first 25 s
baseSample = data(time <= initialTimeMax); % take part of the data corresponding to the first 25 s
baseSampleAverage = mean(baseSample); % take average to deal with noise
data = data - baseSampleAverage;
```

If you don't know when your data starts, you can apply a smoothing filter, then take a derivative, find the x-position of its maximum, and set `initialTimeMax` to this x-position.

Comment: thanks I've updated OP to better explain, it think your solution helps with one part of the problem

Comment: @torr: If you ask additional questions, I can try to expand the answer. What are you missing?

Comment: the last part of OP indicates that I need to get output values that represent a percentage of the original raw value. I think your code does the first part of subtracting the baseline average from all subsequent values but it won't give me that "relative enhancement" value. does this make sense?